# Optimize re-render between brother compounds

Tags: reactjs, optimization

I have a simple TODO application

**The main point of the project is to learn how to build a project in the most optimized way with as few unnecessary re-rendrings as possible**

My component tree is very simple,
APP is the parent of two components:

1. LIST
2. HEADER

HEDER
Displays names of users
LIST will display each user's tasks

**What I want to do:**
I want a variable in the APP that contains the active user at that moment.
By clicking on a username in the HEDER
The active user will change and accordingly LIST will display the tasks of that user.

In the past I would use USESTATE but this makes the APP run again and that is not the goa.

**what do I have :**
I manage to change the active user without rendering the application by using USEREF.

But I didn't find a way to make the LIST render without rendering the APP.

**In simple words I want the HEDER component
Activate rendering for the LIST component
without rendering the APP**

I tried listening for USEREF changes but it doesn't work.
What should I do?
Below is the code:

***APP***

```
export default function App() {

  console.log("App run")
  const todosArr = useRef<task_T_Model[]>([])   /* an arry of tasks later to br used */
  
  let activeUser = useRef<user_T_model | undefined>(
    usersArr.find((user) => user.admin === true)
  )

  // ==============================================================
  const shoulsListUpdate = useRef<boolean>(false)

  // const [UpdateList, setUpdateList] = useState(false)   /* It works but then all the code in the APP runs again */

  const updateList = (user: user_T_model) => {
    activeUser.current = user
    console.log(user)
    shoulsListUpdate.current = !shoulsListUpdate.current
    console.log("from updateList", shoulsListUpdate.current)
    // setUpdateList(prev => !prev)
  }

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Heder updateList={updateList} />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />

        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Navigate replace to={"/Adir"} />} />
          <Route path='/:userid' element={<List test={activeUser.current} />} />
        </Routes>

      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

***HEDER***

```
type Props = {
  updateList: Function
}

export default function Heder({ updateList }: Props) {


  return (

    <AppBar id='heder-bar' >
      <Toolbar disableGutters>
        {
          usersArr.map((user) => (
            <h1 key={user.userid}
              onClick={() => updateList(user)}
            ><Link to={`/${user.userName}`} >{user.userName}</Link></h1>

          ))
        }
      </Toolbar>
    </AppBar>

  )
}
```

***LIST***

```
type Test_Props = {
  test: user_T_model | undefined
}

export default function List({ test }: Test_Props) {


  console.log("list run")
  console.log(test)


  return (
    <div>

      <h1>{test?.userName}   </h1>
      <h1>{test?.userName}   </h1>
      <h1>{test?.userName}   </h1>
      <h1>{test?.userName}   </h1>
      <h1>{test?.userName}   </h1>
      <h1>{test?.userName}   </h1>
      <h1>{test?.userName}   </h1>
      <h1>{test?.userName}   </h1>
      <h1>{test?.userName}   </h1>

    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current setup, you need to utilize `states` but not `refs`, and the app needs to be re-rendered on every click to achieve what you have described.

However, you can do some improvements later on to keep re-rendering as low as possible

1. You can manage your `states` in the components that are desired to be rendered.

   - When a state is changed, it triggers rendering for that component and its children, parents will not be rendered
2. You can use `redux`. It allows you to use and update your states all across the app

   - You do not need to manage your states in parent components, then drill them into children.
   - This will avoid your parent components to re-render
3. Utilize `useMemo`and `React.memo`

   - In simplest explanation, React.memo avoids unnecessary children render.
   - useMemo avoids unnecessary function calls (it might reduce state updates, so the total number of re-rendering)

Comment: In what way would you recommend building such a plan in advance?

Comment: In a simple app those micro managements does not really matter. It gets important when the app grows. You will figure out which way to choose, depending not only on  number of re-rendering but also your app's specifics.